# Why do many audio players interpret my mono AAC (m4a) files as stereo?

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder, aac, m4a, channel

In my iPhone app I record audio files in AAC (m4a container) in `mono` using `AVAudioRecorder`, i.e. I explicitly set

```
[recordSettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
```

When opening those files in audio editors like [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net) they only show one channel as expected. However, there are many popular audio players like [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) or [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) that interpret the file as `stereo`. E.g. when I display the `Media Information... > Codec Details` in VLC it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot VLC]

Interestingly, files recorded with Apple's *Voice Memo* app on the iPhone show the same behavior. They appear to be `stereo` files in several audio players but when I open them in Audacity it turns out they only have one channel.

I cannot believe that all those well-known media players are buggy. So is there some way to tell `AVAudioRecorder` to set the channel number in a way so that all major media players can detect it properly?

Answer (score 5):

(I know this is an old thread, but for the sake of
anybody googling here...) The answer appears to be that
AAC (I'm assuming your encoder uses AAC-HE) always
encodes to two-channel mono - in other words, the audio
itself is downmixed to mono, but the file it's in
consists of two separate audio channels, each with
identical audio to the other. 
It's interesting that your install of Audacity apparently
shows it as one channel - mine shows it as two. To date
I've found no way to force any AAC-encoded file to one
channel.